# Is there any solution for growth the size of data and log file in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I can create a database in SQL Server using this SQL statement:

```
create database test on
[
    (
        [NAME= LogicalName, FILENAME= 'PhysicalName', 
        [,SIZE= Size] [,MAXSIZE= MaxSize | UNLIMITED]
        
    ) [,...n]
```

How to handle `FILEGROWTH` in this case?

I expect you to give me a solution with examples.

Comment: you can play around with it in SSMS and then click on Script, it will display you the actual syntax. It's a good way to learn

Comment: *"How to handle FILEGROWTH in this case?"* Can you elaborate? Hand it *how*..?

Comment: *"I expected to give me solution with examples"* What's wrong with the many examples in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql)?

Answer (score 0):

I could find this solution

```
CREATE DATABASE DbName 
ON [ ( [NAME = LogicalName, 
        FILENAME = 'PhysicalName',  
        [,SIZE= Size] [,MAXSIZE= MaxSize | UNLIMITED] 
        [,FILEGROWTH= Growth] ) [,...n] 
        [LOG ON ( [NAME= LogicalName, FILENAME= 'PhysicalName',  [,SIZE= Size] [,MAXSIZE= MaxSize | UNLIMITED] [,FILEGROWTH= Growth] )[,...n] ]
```